# Count grouped observations that meet conditions using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have hourly/daily stock return data similar to the following:

```
  set.seed(1)
  dt <- data.table(stock = c(rep("a",24),rep("b",24),rep("c",24),rep("d",24)),
  hour = rep(1:24,4), day1 = sample(-5:5,96,replace = TRUE), 
  day2 = sample(-10:-1,96,replace = TRUE), day3 = sample(0:10,96,replace = TRUE),
  day4 = 0)
```

Which looks like:

```
  stock hour    day1    day2    day3    day4
  a      1      -3       -6      1       0
  a      2      -1       -6      10      0
  a      3       1       -2      3       0
  ...                   
  d      22      4       -5      1       0
  d      23      3       -3      3       0
  d      24      3       -7      1       0
```

I would like to count the following for each day:

1. how many stocks show negative returns for all hours
2. how many stocks show positive returns for all hours
3. how many stocks show mixed positive and negative returns during 24 hours
4. how many stocks show at least one zero during 24 hours
5. how many stocks show zero for all 24 hours

The output should look similar to this:

```
  counts                            day1    day2    day3    day4
  stocks_where_all_hours_negative   0       4       0       0
  stocks_where_all_hours_positive   0       0       4       0
  stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg    4       0       0       0
  stocks_where_at_least_one_zero    4       0       2       4
  stocks_where_all_zero             0       0       0       4
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mdt <- melt(
  dt,
  id.vars = c('stock', 'hour'),
  measure.vars = c('day1', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4'),
  variable.name = 'day',
  value.name = 'position'
)
counts <- mdt[ ,.(stocks_where_all_hours_negative = all(position < 0),
        stocks_where_all_hours_positive = all(position > 0),
        stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg = any(position < 0) & any(position > 0),
        stocks_where_at_least_one_zero = any(position != 0),
        stocks_where_all_zero = all(position == 0)),
     by = c('day',
            'stock')][ ,.(stocks_where_all_hours_negative = sum(stocks_where_all_hours_negative),
                          stocks_where_all_hours_positive = sum(stocks_where_all_hours_positive),
                          stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg = sum(stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg),
                          stocks_where_at_least_one_zero = sum(stocks_where_at_least_one_zero),
                          stocks_where_all_zero = sum(stocks_where_all_zero)),
                       by = 'day']
t(counts)
```

First reshape the data to 'long' format so that you can group by days. `any` and `all` functions will check the logic for each vector and return the scenarios you have set up.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @troh.  It works great.  `all(position < 0)` counts when `position` for all hours is less than zero.  How would I count when all nonzero positions are less than zero (ie ignore zeroes when counting `all(position < 0)`)?

Comment: @FG7 I'm not sure I'm following. `all(position < 0)` only counts non-zero negative numbers. `all(position <=0)` would count zero and non-zero.

Comment: To clarify @troh, if, for example, the values for position were -1,-2,-3, and the rest of the 24 hours were zero, `all(position < 0)` would be false, since the zeroes don't meet the condition `all(position < 0)`.  I would like to count it as true since all nonzero values are negative.  If I used `all(position <= 0)`, it would count as true the situation where all 24 hours are zero, which I don't want.  Does that make sense?

Comment: `any(position < 0)` & `!any(position > 0)`

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much @troh for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: For your second step, you can avoid typing all the names again by using `lapply(.SD, sum)` with appropriate `.SDcols=`, I suspect.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Frank.  It definitely helped simplify the code. 
 Here's what I used for the second step summing all the counts : `[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = 3:ncol(counts), by = "day"]`

Answer (score 1):

Since the summary you are doing is so highly specialized, you could write your own function:

```
summarize_stocks <- function(stock, day, return_names = FALSE){
  if(!return_names) return( c(length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) all(x<0)))])),
                              length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) all(x>0)))])),
                              length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) any(x>0) & any(x<0)))])),
                              length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) any(x==0)))])),
                              length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) all(x==0)))]))
                              ))
  else return(c("stocks_where_all_hours_negative", "stocks_where_all_hours_positive", "stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg",
                  "stocks_where_at_least_one_zero", "stocks_where_all_zero"))
}

res <- dt[, lapply(.SD, summarize_stocks, stock = stock), .SDcols = c("day1","day2", "day3", "day4")]
res[, counts := summarize_stocks(return_names = TRUE)]

res
#       day1 day2 day3 day4                          counts
#1:    0    4    0    0 stocks_where_all_hours_negative
#2:    0    0    2    0 stocks_where_all_hours_positive
#3:    4    0    0    0  stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg
#4:    4    0    2    4  stocks_where_at_least_one_zero
#5:    0    0    0    4           stocks_where_all_zero
```

---

Or if you want to get fancy you could change your `summarize_stocks` to:

```
summarize_stocks <- function(stock, day, return_names = FALSE){
  funs <- list(function(x) all(x<0),
               function(x) all(x>0),
               function(x) any(x>0) & any(x<0),
               function(x) any(x==0),
               function(x) all(x==0))

  if(!return_names) return( vapply(funs, function(f) length(unique(stock[as.logical(ave(day, stock, FUN = function(x) f(x)))])), numeric(1L)))

  else return(c("stocks_where_all_hours_negative", "stocks_where_all_hours_positive", "stocks_where_mixed_pos_and_neg",
                  "stocks_where_at_least_one_zero", "stocks_where_all_zero"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help @Mike H.  Your answer works perfectly. 
 I selected the answer by **troh** mainly because my original data is already in long format (so I can skip the melt step) and, as a personal preference, I find the script a bit more readable.